# matlab invalid mex file - how do I get caffe to recognize that I am not using a gpu?

Tags: matlab, caffe

I'm running a matlab (with matlab 2017a) file on ubuntu 14.04 and get the following error:

```
Invalid MEX-file
/home/..../myproject/caffe-cedn-dev/matlab/caffe/caffe.mexa64':
Missing dependent shared libraries:
'libcurdart.so.7.0' required by '/home/.../caffe.mexa64'
'libcublas.so.7.0' required by '/home/.../caffe.mexa64'
```

and some other libraries associated with CUDA and gpus

then
    Missing symbol 'cublasCreate_v2' required by .. '/home/.../caffe.mexa64'
... and other cuBLAS or related symbols

The error originates in the line

```
if caffe('is_initialized') == 0
```

inside the function

```
matcaffe_init(use_gpu, model-def_file, [])
```

I thought that changing `use_gpu` variable to false would avoid the problem of having to install any libraries but this did not change the error.(I also do not have a gpu)

Comment: Build your caffe without GPU support. The problem here is that your caffe binary is linked against those GPU libraries and attempts to load them even if you don't use a GPU. You could also try to put the necessary CUDA runtime libraries in your dynamic linker path, but specify not to use the GPU in Matlab. That might work.

Comment: I have one caffe built that I installed normally - I can test it out in python and it works fine. This library (https://github.com/wasidennis/ObjectFlow) has it's own caffe library attached that I hadn't noticed. After making that and changing all of the options so that it was CPU only (uncommenting CPU_ONLY := 1 in Makefile.config and Makefile.config.example, in CMakeLists.txt changing build(CPU_ONLY) to ON) and doing a cmake following https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2348, I ran it again and got the same error.

Comment: Something in your build process is still linking against these libraries, if you got the same error.  You'll need to scrub that.

Comment: What do you mean by linking against? Right now I'm installing a different Matlab version, as the caffe installation says it doesn't interface with my version.